# Min length not working in below code. When I give blank value for Name, it passes the schema validation (it should throw error)

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, soapui, xsd-validation

Min length not working in below code. When I give blank value for FirstName, it passes the schema validation in SOAP UI (it should throw error).

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="1" name="FirstName" default="John" >
            <xsd:simpleType>
                <xsd:union>
                    <xsd:simpleType>
                        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                        <xsd:minLength value="1"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="John"/>
                        <xsd:enumeration value="Kyle"/>
                        </xsd:restriction>
                    </xsd:simpleType>
                </xsd:union>
            </xsd:simpleType>
            </xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 1):

It passes validation because when you supply an empty value for the element, the effective value is the default value "John", which is valid against the type.

Comment: Thanks Michael. How can I add a minlength restriction of 1 on it before it takes the default value? I tried to add the default inside restriction after minlength but default is not valid inside restriction

Comment: If you don't want to allow empty content, then don't define a default value.

Comment: That is the requirement :) I have to!!

Comment: That's a contradiction. You can't say "If the content is empty, use X as a default" and "the content isn't allowed to be empty" at the same time.

Comment: The requirement is as below - 
Default the value to "ABC" but if I manually delete the value from SOAP UI, it should throw an error saying the value cannot be blank. Does that still sound contradictory to you?

Comment: I don't think you have understood what "default" means in XSD. It means "if the value is blank then treat it as "ABC". You can't treat it as "ABC" and treat it as an error at the same time.